# QT Serialport GUI and worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, serial-port

First things first, I'm a newbie in QT so don't blame me. I know that many similar questions have been in the forum, but I couldn't solve my problem.
Problem description. I want to have a GUI application that receives and parses data and update some qt widget. Formerly I did them all in the Mainwindow thread, but since it hangs, I tried to make it multi-threaded. But it still hangs when I try to update GUI data as fast as 10 ms.

Now, this is what I have tried.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

```
class Parser : public QThread , public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Parser(QThread *parent = nullptr);
    ~Parser();
signals:
    void data1Available(unsigned char*);
    void data2Available(unsigned char*);
    void finished();

    // QRunnable interface
public:
    void run();

public slots:
    void parse();

};
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect( &SerialPort, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(ReadData()) );
    QThread* thread  = new QThread;
    thread->setObjectName("Parser Thread");
    qInfo()<<"Parser Thread";
    Parser* parser= new  Parser();
    parser->moveToThread(thread);

    QObject::connect(thread,&QThread::started,parser,&Parser::run);
    QObject::connect(parser,&Parser::finished,parser,&Parser::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(parser,&Parser::finished,thread,&QThread::quit);
    QObject::connect(thread,&QThread::finished,thread,&QThread::deleteLater);
    QObject::connect(parser,SIGNAL(data1Available(unsigned char *)),this,SLOT(on_data1Available(unsigned char *)));
    QObject::connect(parser,SIGNAL(data2Available(unsigned char *)),this,SLOT(on_data2Available(unsigned char *)));

    thread->start();
}
```

```
void MainWindow::ReadData()
{

    QByteArray Data = SerialPort.readAll();

    for (unsigned char i=0;i<Data.length();i++)
        circBuff.append(Data[i]);
}
```

```
void MainWindow::on_data1Available(unsigned char* tempData)
{
    ui->label1->setNum(tempData[5]);
}
void MainWindow::on_data2Available(unsigned char* tempData)
{
    ui->label2->setNum(tempData[7]);
}
```

```
void Parser::run()
{
    qInfo()<<this<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<QThread::currentThread();

    QScopedPointer<QEventLoop> loop (new QEventLoop);
    QScopedPointer<QTimer> timer (new QTimer);

    timer->setInterval(5);

    connect(timer.data(),&QTimer::timeout,this,&Parser::parse);
    connect(this,&Parser::finished,loop.data(),&QEventLoop::quit);

    timer->start();
    loop->exec();

    qInfo()<<this<<"Finished... "<<QThread::currentThread();

}
```

```
void Parser::parse()
{
    unsigned char tempData[16];
    while (1)
    {
        while (circBuff.size()>=16)
        {
            if ( )
            {
                if ()
                     emit data1Available(tempData);
                else
                     emit data2Available(tempData);
             }
       }
   }
emit finished();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  Note that there really shouldn't be any need to use threads for this.  I suspect the reason for the 'hang' is the same for both the single and multi threaded versions -- specifically, your `parse` function is an infinite loop that never hands control back to Qt's event loop.

Comment: @G.M. What is your suggestion for me? I come from the electrical engineering zone to software engineering, there we use the FreeRTOS task with an infinite loop on microcontrollers. I think you are leading me to use events. Am I right?

Comment: Hi, could you put comments on your code written so far? Put it in a list. Something like this: step 1: receive data from serial port; step 2: wait until buffer is full; step 3: emit a signal; step 4: connect to a slot; step 5: the slot function changes the label. In this way, it's easier to understand.

Comment: @vahidajal Yes, you need to make use of the Qt event loop.  Have a look at the various [serial comms examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-examples.html).

Comment: When dealing with qserialport ive always made a separate wrapper class that instantiates qserialport objest. Then adding public slots to my wrapper for all functionality i want. Inside the slots i call the serialport functions. Then created a qthread and inside its QThread::run function instantiated my wrapper instance before calling exec(). Then the wrapper (and serialport) has event loop and by creating signals to connect to the slots with qt::blockingqueuedconnection type i could then access the serial port by emitting signals. Sorry on a mobile so no proper tags :)